# DexException with FirebaseUI: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzeg;

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I'm trying to include Firebase Authentication (specifically, Email/Password Authentication using FirebaseUI Auth) in a project. Since I'm a novice, I'm using the examples of a book ("Firebase Essentials Android Edition"). They work as expected, the problem appears when I'm forced to use:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.2.0'
```

instead of the version `11.0.4` suggested in the book (in order to use google maps). The ability to sign out and delete account stops working.

I've searched info and I'm trying to update all I can. I'm using Android Studio 2.3.3. Currently, I have the following `build.gradle` scripts:

project build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.doov.firetest"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

But when I build I get the next error (I've seen them at other times, that's why I made a"generic" question that maybe could solve all these types of questions):

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.>
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException:
>   Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzeg;

How do I solve it?
Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.

Comment: When you see `com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define X` you should execute `gradlew app:dependencies --configuration releaseCompileClasspath`. Output helps to find solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using:

```
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.0.1'
```

Check the [official doc.](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android)
**You need to make sure that you use the same version that your chosen version of FirebaseUI requires.**

```
FirebaseUI Version  ->  Firebase/Play Services Version    
     3.1.0              11.4.2
     3.0.0              11.4.2 
     2.4.0              11.4.0
     2.3.0              11.0.4
     2.2.0              11.0.4
```

You have to use:

```
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:3.1.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.0'
```

or another combination as in the table.